# Why the speak recognition score is 0

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I use cognitive speech sdk sample to create a Speaker Recognition profiler, it works fine, the result score is 0.8, then I want to reuse the profile, but the score is always 0.
Where am I wrong?

```
void TextIndependentVerification(shared_ptr<VoiceProfileClient> client, shared_ptr<SpeakerRecognizer> recognizer)
{
    std::cout << "Text Independent Verification:\n\n";
    
    auto profile = VoiceProfile::FromId("3b32c3dc-a974-497f-b6af-7cda3b607751");

    std::cout << "Created profile ID: " << profile->GetId() << "\n";

    SpeakerVerify(profile, recognizer);
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below REST API to verify existing profiles against input audio.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/verification/textindependent/verifyprofile

Using the SDK you can use the following [helper](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/995d20d9d49b8a054c8141030ad647b5bf5fefd6/quickstart/csharp/dotnet/speaker-recognition/helloworld/Program.cs#L18) function and to verify pass the existing voice profile.